# help with looping in php

Tags: php, parsing, loops

I have a need of scraping information from text files that comes in format like so:
I know how to get the delimiter from between the quotes. using that delimiter i have to go through each section, and set the name in one variable and information between delimiter in another variable. Need to continue doing until it reaches end of file.

```
test.txt
-------------------------
delimiter: "--@--"

--@-- 

name:"section1"

This is section 1 with some information

--@--

name:"section2"

This is section 2 with some information

--@--

name:"section3"

this is section 3 with some information

--@--
```

End of file

i appreciate all the help i get. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: [file_get_contents](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [str_split](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) will get you what you want.

Comment: Additionally, it may be helpful if you post 'test.txt' as-is, without your comments inserted. It is hard to tell what is data and what is commentary.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: That wouldn't really work if the file is more than a few hundred MB. If the file is row based fgets() might be what he wants.

Comment: @jishi: if the file is large, I agree. I was only going on what I was given.

Comment: as is text file is following:test.txt
delimiter: "--@--"

--@-- 

name:"section1"

This is section 1 with some information

--@--

name:"section2"

This is section 2 with some information

--@--

name:"section3"

this is section 3 with some information

--@--

Comment: Is this some MIME multipart message?

Comment: @jdk: Please check my edit to your question, and confirm that your text file looks exactly like that, including the newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering your text file content is in $string and delimiter is $delim, a preg_match_all and a array_combine will help you with this

```
$delim = preg_quote($delim,'/');
preg_match_all('/(?<='.$delim.')\s*name:"([^"]+)"\s*(.*?)\s*(?='.$delim.')/',$string,$m);
$items = array_combine($m[1],$m[2]);
```

it should return somthing like this:

```
Array
(
    [section1] => This is section 1 with some information
    [section2] => This is section 2 with some information
    [section3] => this is section 3 with some information
)
```

Comment: perfect, so from there i can do foreach($items as $name => $content) {     // Do processing here. }  to do whatever other parsing i need?

Comment: yes you can foreach($items as $name => $content) {
    // Do processing here.
}

Comment: for some reason preg_match_all = 0 :(

Comment: preg_match_all comes out to 0 because when i use file_get_contents the test.txt becomes one big string w/o any newline

Comment: the regular expression above should work without newline chars as it only consider blank spaces (tab, new line, carriage return, space...). But if your section information is more than one line it will fail. to make it work with multiline section content you have to had a s at the end of the regexp: '/(?<='.$delim.')\s*name:"([^"]+)"\s*(.*?)\s*(?='.$delim.')/s' It's weird that you don't see new lines chars. Are you sure that there's no new lines at all or is this just the way your editor expect new line (CR+LF or\r\n instead of only LF or \n)

Comment: its the way file_get_contents put everything in one big string when i do $string = file_get_contents(test.txt); (above regexp doesn't work also. could it be because there are other strings between delimiter and "name" whereas in the above example there is only space? i don't see any other (CR+LF or\r\n instead of only LF or \n) etc

Comment: Yes the above regexp can't work if you have other chars than blank ones between delimiter and name. what is really in your file, have you a real world sample ?

Comment: yes, my variable $string contains "this is a test message. i need to parse this file that has important information: this message is simple text; boundary="--@--" this is plain text email which has all the information requried . --@-- starting message from here --@-- this is plain text email; name="section1" reading this text should be fairly easy. --@-- starting another section; name="section2" With rest of the information like so tsa = calling subject: computer science grade:34 date: 6/21/2011 --@--" when i print it out.

Comment: from this i want to read anything between the boundary that has "name" in it. so output would be section1: reading this text should be fairly easy. section2: with rest of the information like so tsa = calling subject: computer science grade:34 date: 6/21/2011 and so on.

Comment: ok, so try this one : '/(?<='.$delim.').*?name:"([^"]+)"\s*(.*?)\s*(?='.$delim.')/s', not tested here but i think it should do the work.

Comment: yes it works now but only for the first time it finds "name:" so i get section1: reading this text should be fairly easy. but second one i don't get...

Comment: That's totally normal, in your first example you use name:"name" and in fact you now have name="name" = and : isn't the same and the original regexp only work for : Finally try this one which should work for both: '/(?<='.$delim.').*?name[:=]"([^"]+)"\s*(.*?)\s*(?='.$delim.')/s'

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, this should do what you need.

```
<?
define(DELIMITER, '--@--');
$fh = fopen('test.txt');
$sections = array();
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    if ($line == DELIMITER)
        continue;
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/name:"(.*)"/i', $line, $matches)) {
        $cursect = $matches[1];
        continue;
    }
    $sections[$cursect] .= $line;
}
fclose($fh);

foreach($sections as $name => $content) {
    // Do processing here.
}
```

Simpler methods are possible using file_get_contents but depending on how large your file is that may not be possible since you would have to load the whole file into memory.

Comment: so i store all content in variable using file_get_contents how would the while statement change?

Comment: If the file is small enough to be stored using file_get_contents, then the code that malko suggested is probably the simplest way of getting all the data.

Comment: this one should work for large file, as said by @EdoDodo use this one on large file, mine will be better for smaller content, the best one for you depends on your real text files.

Comment: size varies in my case, it can be super small or big size. it will be combination of both. Thanks to both @edoDodo and @malko. i accept both solutions.